# iphone best way derive UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, derived-class

I wish create my personal UITableViewController and use it into my UIViewController using interface builder...
what's the best and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use the Interface Builder you Probably wanna check this nice tutorial:

http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1977-Building-a-Simple-UITableView-for-iPhone-Apps